# Converting list requested from api to dataframe AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, api

trying to get intraday historical data for some years from eod api [eod intraday api](https://eodhistoricaldata.com/financial-apis/intraday-historical-data-api/)

```
from datetime import datetime
dates=[ '01-01-2021','01-04-2021','01-07-2021','01-10-2021',
        '01-01-2022','01-04-2022','01-07-2022']

# Convert your strings to datetime, using `datetime` library
dates = [datetime.strptime(date, "%d-%m-%Y") for date in dates]



def create_df(pair,dates):
    df = []
    for index, elem in enumerate(dates):
        if index== 0:
            curr_date = str(elem.timestamp())
            next_date = str(dates[index+1].timestamp())
            df = client.get_prices_intraday(pair, interval = '1m', from_ = curr_date, to = next_date)
        elif ((index>0) & (index+1 < len(dates))):
            curr_date = str(elem.timestamp())
            next_date = str(dates[index+1].timestamp())
            df2 = client.get_prices_intraday(pair, interval = '1m', from_ = curr_date, to = next_date)
            df.append(df2)
    return df






from eod import EodHistoricalData
# create the instance of the SDK
api_key = 'my_api_key'
client = EodHistoricalData(api_key)




GBPAUD = create_df('GBPAUD.FOREX',dates)
```

what gives me something like:

```
GBPAUD


[{'timestamp': 1609693200,
  'gmtoffset': 0,
  'datetime': '2021-01-03 17:00:00',
  'open': 1.77086,
  'high': 1.77086,
  'low': 1.77086,
  'close': 1.77086,
  'volume': 1},
 {'timestamp': 1609693260,
  'gmtoffset': 0,
  'datetime': '2021-01-03 17:01:00',
  'open': 1.77086,
  'high': 1.77086,
  'low': 1.77086,
  'close': 1.77086,
  'volume': 1},
 {'timestamp': 1609693320,
  'gmtoffset': 0,
  'datetime': '2021-01-03 17:02:00',
  'open': 1.77086,
  'high': 1.77086,
  'low': 1.77086,
  'close': 1.77086,
  'volume': 1},
 {'timestamp': 1609693380,
  'gmtoffset': 0,
  'datetime': '2021-01-03 17:03:00',
  'open': 1.77086,
  'high': 1.77222,
  'low': 1.77086,
  'close': 1.77199,
  'volume': 14},
 {'timestamp': 1609693440,
  'gmtoffset': 0,
  'datetime': '2021-01-03 17:04:00',
  'open': 1.77203,
  'high': 1.77348,
  'low': 1.77176,
  'close': 1.77199,
  'volume': 23},
```

that is stored as a list, but when I try to convert to pandas dataframe :

```
GBPAUD = pd.DataFrame(GBPAUD)
```

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
> last) Input In [39], in <cell line: 1>()
> ----> 1 GBPAUD = pd.DataFrame(GBPAUD)
>
> File
> ~/anaconda3/envs/rapids-22.02/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:694,
> in DataFrame.**init**(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
> 689     if columns is not None:
> 690         # error: Argument 1 to "ensure_index" has incompatible type
> 691         # "Collection[Any]"; expected "Union[Union[Union[ExtensionArray,
> 692         # ndarray], Index, Series], Sequence[Any]]"
> 693         columns = ensure_index(columns)  # type: ignore[arg-type]
> --> 694     arrays, columns, index = nested_data_to_arrays(
> 695         # error: Argument 3 to "nested_data_to_arrays" has incompatible
> 696         # type "Optional[Collection[Any]]"; expected "Optional[Index]"
> 697         data,
> 698         columns,
> 699         index,  # type: ignore[arg-type]
> 700         dtype,
> 701     )
> 702     mgr = arrays_to_mgr(
> 703         arrays,
> 704         columns,    (...)
> 708         typ=manager,
> 709     )
> 710 else:
>
> File
> ~/anaconda3/envs/rapids-22.02/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py:483,
> in nested_data_to_arrays(data, columns, index, dtype)
> 480 if is_named_tuple(data[0]) and columns is None:
> 481     columns = ensure_index(data[0]._fields)
> --> 483 arrays, columns = to_arrays(data, columns, dtype=dtype)
> 484 columns = ensure_index(columns)
> 486 if index is None:
>
> File
> ~/anaconda3/envs/rapids-22.02/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py:799,
> in to_arrays(data, columns, dtype)
> 797     arr = _list_to_arrays(data)
> 798 elif isinstance(data[0], abc.Mapping):
> --> 799     arr, columns = _list_of_dict_to_arrays(data, columns)
> 800 elif isinstance(data[0], ABCSeries):
> 801     arr, columns = _list_of_series_to_arrays(data, columns)
>
> File
> ~/anaconda3/envs/rapids-22.02/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py:884,
> in _list_of_dict_to_arrays(data, columns)
> 882     gen = (list(x.keys()) for x in data)
> 883     sort = not any(isinstance(d, dict) for d in data)
> --> 884     pre_cols = lib.fast_unique_multiple_list_gen(gen, sort=sort)
> 885     columns = ensure_index(pre_cols)
> 887 # assure that they are of the base dict class and not of derived
> 888 # classes
>
> File
> ~/anaconda3/envs/rapids-22.02/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/lib.pyx:400,
> in pandas._libs.lib.fast_unique_multiple_list_gen()
>
> File
> ~/anaconda3/envs/rapids-22.02/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py:882,
> in (.0)
> 862 """
> 863 Convert list of dicts to numpy arrays
> 864     (...)
> 879 columns : Index
> 880 """
> 881 if columns is None:
> --> 882     gen = (list(x.keys()) for x in data)
> 883     sort = not any(isinstance(d, dict) for d in data)
> 884     pre_cols = lib.fast_unique_multiple_list_gen(gen, sort=sort)
>
> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'

anybody has a more elegant way to get a lot of data from that api, or a way to fix the error ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your example data read into pandas correctly (after closing the list).  Without looking at your data (please share a snippet instead of a link to sign up for a service), in your for loop, you're adding your data in to the `df` variable in two different ways which creates a list of lists after a single list and no key.  That is what pandas is complaining about.  In the below example, which has a minimized version of your code, and uses your data as an input, observe the output after:

```
data = [{'timestamp': 1609693200,
  'gmtoffset': 0,
  'datetime': '2021-01-03 17:00:00',
  'open': 1.77086,
  'high': 1.77086,
  'low': 1.77086,
  'close': 1.77086,
  'volume': 1},
 {'timestamp': 1609693260,
  'gmtoffset': 0,
  'datetime': '2021-01-03 17:01:00',
  'open': 1.77086,
  'high': 1.77086,
  'low': 1.77086,
  'close': 1.77086,
  'volume': 1},
 {'timestamp': 1609693320,
  'gmtoffset': 0,
  'datetime': '2021-01-03 17:02:00',
  'open': 1.77086,
  'high': 1.77086,
  'low': 1.77086,
  'close': 1.77086,
  'volume': 1},
 {'timestamp': 1609693380,
  'gmtoffset': 0,
  'datetime': '2021-01-03 17:03:00',
  'open': 1.77086,
  'high': 1.77222,
  'low': 1.77086,
  'close': 1.77199,
  'volume': 14},
 {'timestamp': 1609693440,
  'gmtoffset': 0,
  'datetime': '2021-01-03 17:04:00',
  'open': 1.77203,
  'high': 1.77348,
  'low': 1.77176,
  'close': 1.77199,
  'volume': 23}]
df = []
dates = [1,2,3]
for index, elem in enumerate(dates):
    if index== 0:
        # df = client.get_prices_intraday(pair, interval = '1m', from_ = curr_date, to = next_date)
        df = data
    elif ((index>0) & (index+1 < len(dates))):
        # df2 = client.get_prices_intraday(pair, interval = '1m', from_ = curr_date, to = next_date)
        df2 = data
        df.append(df2)
print(df)
```

your output is:

```
[{'timestamp': 1609693200, 'gmtoffset': 0, 'datetime': '2021-01-03 17:00:00', 'open': 1.77086, 'high': 1.77086, 'low': 1.77086, 'close': 1.77086, 'volume': 1}, {'timestamp': 1609693260, 'gmtoffset': 0, 'datetime': '2021-01-03 17:01:00', 'open': 1.77086, 'high': 1.77086, 'low': 1.77086, 'close': 1.77086, 'volume': 1}, {'timestamp': 1609693320, 'gmtoffset': 0, 'datetime': '2021-01-03 17:02:00', 'open': 1.77086, 'high': 1.77086, 'low': 1.77086, 'close': 1.77086, 'volume': 1}, {'timestamp': 1609693380, 'gmtoffset': 0, 'datetime': '2021-01-03 17:03:00', 'open': 1.77086, 'high': 1.77222, 'low': 1.77086, 'close': 1.77199, 'volume': 14}, {'timestamp': 1609693440, 'gmtoffset': 0, 'datetime': '2021-01-03 17:04:00', 'open': 1.77203, 'high': 1.77348, 'low': 1.77176, 'close': 1.77199, 'volume': 23}, [...], [...]]
```

See the two lists it has at the end?  What I think you wanted, using the same list data, was this

```
df = []
dates = [1,2,3]
for date in dates:
        df += data
print(df)
```

which outputs this:

```
[{'timestamp': 1609693200, 'gmtoffset': 0, 'datetime': '2021-01-03 17:00:00', 'open': 1.77086, 'high': 1.77086, 'low': 1.77086, 'close': 1.77086, 'volume': 1}, {'timestamp': 1609693260, 'gmtoffset': 0, 'datetime': '2021-01-03 17:01:00', 'open': 1.77086, 'high': 1.77086, 'low': 1.77086, 'close': 1.77086, 'volume': 1}, {'timestamp': 1609693320, 'gmtoffset': 0, 'datetime': '2021-01-03 17:02:00', 'open': 1.77086, 'high': 1.77086, 'low': 1.77086, 'close': 1.77086, 'volume': 1}, {'timestamp': 1609693380, 'gmtoffset': 0, 'datetime': '2021-01-03 17:03:00', 'open': 1.77086, 'high': 1.77222, 'low': 1.77086, 'close': 1.77199, 'volume': 14}, {'timestamp': 1609693440, 'gmtoffset': 0, 'datetime': '2021-01-03 17:04:00', 'open': 1.77203, 'high': 1.77348, 'low': 1.77176, 'close': 1.77199, 'volume': 23}, {'timestamp': 1609693200, 'gmtoffset': 0, 'datetime': '2021-01-03 17:00:00', 'open': 1.77086, 'high': 1.77086, 'low': 1.77086, 'close': 1.77086, 'volume': 1}, {'timestamp': 1609693260, 'gmtoffset': 0, 'datetime': '2021-01-03 17:01:00', 'open': 1.77086, 'high': 1.77086, 'low': 1.77086, 'close': 1.77086, 'volume': 1}, {'timestamp': 1609693320, 'gmtoffset': 0, 'datetime': '2021-01-03 17:02:00', 'open': 1.77086, 'high': 1.77086, 'low': 1.77086, 'close': 1.77086, 'volume': 1}, {'timestamp': 1609693380, 'gmtoffset': 0, 'datetime': '2021-01-03 17:03:00', 'open': 1.77086, 'high': 1.77222, 'low': 1.77086, 'close': 1.77199, 'volume': 14}, {'timestamp': 1609693440, 'gmtoffset': 0, 'datetime': '2021-01-03 17:04:00', 'open': 1.77203, 'high': 1.77348, 'low': 1.77176, 'close': 1.77199, 'volume': 23}, {'timestamp': 1609693200, 'gmtoffset': 0, 'datetime': '2021-01-03 17:00:00', 'open': 1.77086, 'high': 1.77086, 'low': 1.77086, 'close': 1.77086, 'volume': 1}, {'timestamp': 1609693260, 'gmtoffset': 0, 'datetime': '2021-01-03 17:01:00', 'open': 1.77086, 'high': 1.77086, 'low': 1.77086, 'close': 1.77086, 'volume': 1}, {'timestamp': 1609693320, 'gmtoffset': 0, 'datetime': '2021-01-03 17:02:00', 'open': 1.77086, 'high': 1.77086, 'low': 1.77086, 'close': 1.77086, 'volume': 1}, {'timestamp': 1609693380, 'gmtoffset': 0, 'datetime': '2021-01-03 17:03:00', 'open': 1.77086, 'high': 1.77222, 'low': 1.77086, 'close': 1.77199, 'volume': 14}, {'timestamp': 1609693440, 'gmtoffset': 0, 'datetime': '2021-01-03 17:04:00', 'open': 1.77203, 'high': 1.77348, 'low': 1.77176, 'close': 1.77199, 'volume': 23}]
```

and reads into pandas or cudf just fine.